# What does it mean if the distribuctions of TP and FP are really similar?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I was training a Neural Network these days, and I plotted the values of TP, FP, TN, FN on the validation set as the training progresses. I found that on the validation set, the distribuctions of TP and FP are really similar, and the distribuctions of TN and FN are really similar. Namely,
it seems that
$$
|TP-FP| = a \quad \text{and} \quad |TN-FN| = b
$$
for some constants $a,b$. Also, the total accuracy is almost a straight line. Does this phenomenon mean anything or is it just a common scene? Does it imply that the Neural Network actually does not learn anything at all?